# How to create a replace operation with sequelize.js?

Tags: sequelize.js

Using sequelize.js with express.js.

I need to replace an existing instance of a model with a new instance. I want the new instance to be validated prior to saving the replacement in order to make sure all required fields are present. However, `validate()` does not work as I would expect. In the following example, `req.body` is missing `requiedId`. I create a new `location`, set `someAttribute` on it from `req.body` and call `validate()`. Since `requiredId` is missing and the model has it defined as `allowNull: false`, I would expect a validation error. This is not the case, and the update happily runs.

```
sequelize.define('location', {
locationId: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  primaryKey: true,
},
requiredId: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
},
someAttribute: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    defaultValue: 'baz'
});

var location;
models.location.findById(locationId)
    .then(function (data) {
         location = data;
         var replacement = models.location.build({});

         // req.body = { someAttribute: 'value' }
         _.assign(replacement, req.body);

         return replacement.validate()
             .then(function () {
                 return location.update(replacement.toJSON());
             });
    }
})
.then(function () {
    res.send('success');
})
.catch(function (err) {
    res.status(400).send({ error:err });
});
```

If I manually add a `null` value for `requiredId`, then the validation error occurs as expected.

```
_.assign(replacement, req.body, { requiredId: null });
replacement.validate().catch(function (err) {
    // now I hit it 
})
```

It appears that when I am building a new instance of a model, sequelize does not validate fields which have not been set.

What is the proper way to implement a `replace` function in sequelize? The old instance should be replaced with a new object containing the required fields and either an explicit value or the default value for any optional fields.

```
var original = { locationId: 1, requiredId: 2, someAttribute: 'foo'};
var new = { locationId: 1, requiredId: 3};
models.location.replace(new);
// => { locationId: 1, requiredId: 3, someAttribute: 'baz' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was confused about how the `validate()` call works. I expected any validation errors to fall through to the `catch()` part of the promise. However, when calling `validate()` directly, validation errors are returned in the callback argument.